# RShiny display multiple leaflet maps on the same plot

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, maps

I have a shiny app where the user can select to display a specific leaflet map (on 51 available), or all leaflet maps (the 51 on 11 columns and 5 rows).

To display multiple leaflet maps on the same plot, I am using latticeView, which works well outside of the shinyapp, but which is not displayed with renderleaflet.

Which render should I use ? Is it possible to use the same render for both the multiple map and the single maps as it is the same plot ID ?

REPREX :

```
require(leaflet)
require(leafsync)
require(shiny)

tilesURL <- "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"

basemap <- list()
for(n in 1:51) {
  basemap[[n]] <- basemap1 <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles(tilesURL) 
}



ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("nb", "Select number", choices = c("All", 1:51))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("map")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    if(input$nb=="All") {
      output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        latticeView(basemap, ncol=11)
      })
    } else {
      output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        basemap[[as.numeric(input$nb)]]
      })
    }
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This code displays the maps if we select the number between 1 and 51, but not if we select "All" as input.

Thanks for help !

EDIT with smartse solution, I get an error :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping to `renderUI` and `uiOutput` instead seems to work:

```
mainPanel(
 uiOutput("map")
)

  observe({
    if(input$nb=="All") {
      output$map <- renderUI({
        latticeView(basemap, ncol=11)
      })
    } else {
      output$map <- renderUI({
        basemap[[as.numeric(input$nb)]]
      })
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, it works to display "All" but not the individual members, I get the following error : Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  [No stack trace available]

Comment: That's strange - I checked that before and I've just checked it again and it works - see the screenshots I've added. Are you just running the example?

Comment: Yes the exact same example and I also copied your code. I've updated my initial post with the code and the error

Comment: Hmm that is strange. The error means that `input$nb` is empty which it shouldn't be... but you could try adding `req(input$nb)` as the first line in the `observe` and see whether that makes a difference - that checks that `input$nb` isn't empty so should stop `if` returning an error.

Comment: It is not empty because it returns "10" from the print I've added just before the output$map. No difference, exact same error if I add "req(input$nb)", very strange...

Comment: yeah I saw that but `if` seems to disagree! How about just getting rid of the `if` and checking whether `basemap[[as.numeric(input$nb)]]` works by itself? That would at least confirm where the problem lies.

Comment: Does not work either, I removed the "if", so I only have the observe({ output$map <- renderUI({
        basemap[[as.numeric(input$nb)]]
      })
  })

But I still have the "Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  [No stack trace available]", which is weird as I have no "if"

Comment: I get rid of this error if I use leafletOutput / renferLeaflet... (But "All" is not displayed)

Comment: Very weird. It must be a package version / OS issue. FWIW I just tried on my Mac (was on ubuntu before) and it also works fine for me on that.

Comment: I've updated all the involved packages and the error remains... Do you have older versions ? Or maybe it is R version. I also am on Windows

Comment: Wouhou I was with R4.0.2, I've updated to R4.3 and it works... now I have to update all my apps with the newer version... Thanks !

Comment: Good good! Glad you sorted it!